# xml using encoding UTF-8 witout BOM groovy

Tags: groovy

Hi I need to create a XML file in groovy using MarkupBuilder class, the xml file should have encoding utf-8 without BOM.

This is my code that generate a markupbuilder and add a encoding

```
    def textXML = new StringWriter()
    def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(textXML)
    builder.setDoubleQuotes(false)
    builder.setOmitNullAttributes(true)
    builder.setOmitEmptyAttributes(true)
    builder.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")
    //some more code
```

This code creates the xml file

```
  def file = new File("fileXml.xml")
  file << textXML
```

But the generate xml is always with encoding utf-8 with BOM

How solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Marker) is always the first three bytes of the file. You can simply remove them.

I would do something like this:

```
def textXML = new StringWriter()
def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(textXML)
builder.setDoubleQuotes(false)
builder.setOmitNullAttributes(true)
builder.setOmitEmptyAttributes(true)
builder.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")

def xmlbytes = textXML.toString().getBytes().flatten()
xmlbytes.remove(0)
xmlbytes.remove(0)
xmlbytes.remove(0)

def file = new File("fileXml.xml")
file << xmlbytes
```

That's how I'd do it. Pardon the java-ness of my Groovy -- old habits die hard.

Answer (score 0):

So my situation is slightly different. I'm trying to write an XML using MarkupBuilder and have the BOM appear (new customer requirement). So far, everything I try yields just a plain text XML file with no BOM. Here's my sample code:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder( writer )
xml.setDoubleQuotes(false)
xml.setOmitNullAttributes(true)
xml.setOmitEmptyAttributes(true)
xml.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")

xml.quote() {
 xml.quote_details() {
  xml.detail() {
   xml.quoteId('Q1339', type:'FCL')
  }
 }
}
new FileOutputStream('UTF_test.xml').withWriter('UTF-8') { w ->
  w.write('ABC')
  w << writer
}
```

The "ABC" will show up in the file, but no BOM. My backup plan is to just export the characters myself, but this seems less elegant.